# OS X 10.9.2 has slowed down MATLAB

Tags: macos, performance

I am using 10.9.2 late 2013 computer to analyze my data, specifically with MATLAB, and generally I have many MATLABs open in parallel, doing some analyses for me. MATLAB, X or Y is completely irrelevant here, so just imagine your best program and replace it with MATLAB here.

I observed that from one day to another my MATLAB processes became extremely slow, without any other apparent performance issues. This started with the following observation, when I started an analysis on the night and checked the progress on the morning, I have observed that MATLAB's speed was extremely slow, compared to the point when I started the analysis, and of course tasks were not completed.

Following, this behavior started to occur as soon as I started any analysis, making me completely unable to finish any analysis within reasonable times.

And I made the observation that, the slowing down of MATLAB was associated with the following message on the Console:

```
3/31/14 03:16:06.318 ReportCrash[554]: Invoking spindump for pid=431 thread=4802 percent_cpu=98 duration=92 because of excessive cpu utilization
```

Now I made a recovery from Time Machine, to a previous state, and all my MATLAB processes are working at full speed again. I am not sure how long this will last, and I have no idea why MATLAB is treated by 10.9.2 this way.

The issue is not related to App Nap, as it is completely disabled.

Below is a screenshot of the Activity Monitor the way how it should always be i.e. all MATLABs at full speed! I am afraid soon MATLAB processes will demoted to a lower priority again by 10.9.2.

[image: Activity Monitor Screenshot]

Comment: impressive editing :D... thx!